# Let $\Omega$ be a countable set $\mathcal A=2^{\Omega}$ be the collection of all subsets of $\Omega$.Then $\dots$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a countable set $\mathcal A=2^{\Omega}$ be the collection of all subsets of $\Omega$.Then

1. If $\mu:A\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is defined by $\mu(E)=|E|$ that
   $|E|$ is number of elements in E.Then $\mu$ is a measure and is
   called the counting measure on $\Omega$.
2. lf $\Omega=\{\omega_{1},\omega_{2},\dots\}$ is an enumeration of
       $\Omega$ and if $\Omega$ is infinite,let
       $A_{n}=\{\omega_{n+1},\omega_{n+2},\dots\}$ then $A_{n}\downarrow
           \emptyset $ and $\mu(\emptyset )=0 \neq \infty=\lim_{n\to \infty}
           \mu(A_{n}).$
3. If $\mu$ is a general, possibly infinite, measure defined on an
   algebra $\mathcal A$ of subsets of any set $\Omega$ , and if
   $A,A_{n}\in \mathcal A$,  $A_{1}\supset A_{2}\supset,\dots
       A=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}$ Then show that $\mu(A)=\lim_{n\to
       \infty}\mu(A_{n})$  provided there exists some $k$ such that
   $\mu(A_{k} )\lt \infty $.

Thanks for help

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What are your ideas on this problem?

Comment: @Stefan.hello this question have several part I can solve others but about them i have no idea.

Comment: @Stefan.Actually for number one that enough use definition of measure and use Triangle inequality I think and for another I have no idea if it possible for you please help to me .thanks

Comment: yes for 1) you only have to check the properties of a measure. For 2): Can you show that  $A_{n}\downarrow \emptyset $? What is $\mu(A_n)$ ?

Comment: @Stefan. i am so sorry I edite number one and $$\mu(A_{n})=|A_{n}|\qquad number\qquad  of\qquad  lements\qquad in\qquad A_{n}$$

Comment: Well, as you can see $A_n$ has an infnite number of elements. Thus $\mu (A_n) = \infty$. Now $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n)  = \infty$, but $\mu(\lim\limits_{n\to \infty } A_n) = \mu (\emptyset) = 0$

Comment: @Stefan.Excuse me how to prove $A_{n}\downarrow \emptyset$? you help me so much. I think if it possible for you write your idea in answer and get score of this question. and whats your idea about number 3? thank you so much.

Comment: I don't see a question mark. Questions usually end with a question mark.

Comment: why you want question mark?. I think question is clear

Comment: @Stefan. thank you for answer.Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry for the late answer, but I was in a hurry yesterday.

2) $A \downarrow \emptyset$ means $A =\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb N} A_n = \emptyset$. Suppose $A \neq \emptyset$. Then $\exists x \in A$, thus $\forall n \in \mathbb N : x \in A_n$. But because $\{\omega_1, \omega_2 ,\dots\}$ is an enumeration, there is an index $i$ with $\omega_i = x$. Now $\omega_i \notin A_n$ for $n > i$, so $x=\omega_i \notin A$.

$\mu(\emptyset) = 0$ (because $\mu$ is a measure). And $\mu (A_n) = \infty$, thus $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \mu(A_n) = \infty \neq 0$.

For 3) take a look at http://www.randomservices.org/random/prob/Measure.html , part 8.